# Generics with polymorphism and factory class

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I made few classes structure and now I have problem with creating them in my factory class.
I have generic interface:

```
interface GenericInterface<T>{
  T someMethod(T instance);
}
```

And subclasses like:

```
class Class_A implements GenericInterface<String>{
  String someMethod(String instance){//impl};
}

class Class_B implements GenericInterface<Integer>{
  Integer someMethod(Integer instance){//impl};
}
```

Now the problem is that I need factory class like:

```
class FactoryClass{
  static <T> GenericInterface<T> getSpecificClass(T instance){
    //errors
    if(instance instanceof String) return new Class_A;
    if(instance instanceof Integer) return new Class_B;
}
```

and somewhere else:

```
String test = "some text";
GenericInterface<String> helper = FactoryClass.getSpecificClass(test);
String afterProcessing = helper.someMethod(test);
```

So for String object as a parameter I should get the `Class_A` instance and for Integer the `Class_B` instance.
Now I have an error that `Class_A` is not subtype of `GenericInterface<T>`. I can change the return type in Factory class to raw type `GenericInterface` but it does not seem to be solution since I've got warnings all over the project then.

Do You have any suggestions how to achieve such functionality, maybe with different design pattern? I need common super interface because of further polymorphic calls of `someMethod()`.

Comment: You could make a cast in FactoryClass, like this:

`return (GenericInterface<T>) new Class_A();`

Answer (score 1):

From your usage, I believe you need an interface like

```
interface GenericInterface<T>{
    T someMethod(T input);
}
```

---

Now, you should have the factory class like

```
class FactoryClass {
    static <T, S extends GenericInterface<T>> S getSpecificClass(T instance) {
        if(instance instanceof String) return new Class_A();
        if(instance instanceof Integer) return new Class_B();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, the type system will probably not be able to ascertain that this is type safe and will emit some warning or even error.

Comment: You might be right, I didn't test this code, just wrote it here.

Comment: I tried it, and as Marko said there is still an error

Comment: So you'll need `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the method and use `return (S) new ...` in all cases. That will do an unchecked cast into the required target type.